# Asynchronously triggering functions when a job has new data in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, events, jobs

I'd like for the console to trigger functions when a job has new data (from a job started with `Start-ThreadJob`), i.e. whenever `.HasMoreData` is True. I was hoping [Register-ObjectEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) would help me in this regard, but unfortunately it seems that there's no event for HasMoreData. There *is* an event for the job's state changing though.

One solution might be to have the job's scriptblock change the state of the job whenever more data is expected, though I'm not sure the best way to do that.

The best solution would probably be to override some part of the ThreadJob class to give it an event related to HasMoreData that can be registered, but that's currently beyond my ability.

Comment: `PSDataCollection<T>` has a `DataAdded` event you can register to. ``[System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1].GetEvents()``. Probably would be better to not use ThreadJob in this case and use runspaces directly. You need to be more specific with your question tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is lacking clarity as to what exactly you want to do on data adding but as an example, instead of using *ThreadJobs* you can use [`powershell` instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) directly, if you invoke them async using one of the [`BeginInvoke<TInput, TOutput>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.begininvoke?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-powershell-begininvoke-2(system-management-automation-psdatacollection((-0))-system-management-automation-psdatacollection((-1)))) overload you can hook a [`PSDataCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatacollection-1?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) and register to its [`DataAdded` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatacollection-1.dataadded?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-psdatacollection-1-dataadded):

```bash
try {
    $ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
        $timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        while ($timer.Elapsed.Seconds -lt 30) {
            Get-Random
            Start-Sleep 1
        }
    }, $true)

    $output = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]]::new()
    $iasync = $ps.BeginInvoke(
        [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]]::new(),
        $output)

    $registerObjectEventSplat = @{
        InputObject      = $output
        EventName        = 'DataAdded'
        SourceIdentifier = 'Testing'
        Action           = {
            foreach ($item in $sender.ReadAll()) {
                "$([datetime]::Now.ToString('s')) - An item was added: '$item'" |
                    Out-Host
            }
        }
    }

    $null = Register-ObjectEvent @registerObjectEventSplat
    Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier Testing
}
finally {
    Unregister-Event Testing
    $ps.Stop()
    $ps.EndInvoke($iasync)
    $ps.Dispose()
    $output.Dispose()
}
```